# Multiple Inheritance issue with EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I am having an issue with multiple inheritance and building my model. I get the error "*The property 'Id' is not a declared property on type...*". Everything worked fine before I added the ContextEntity class and I had a TPC model. Each (non abstract)derived entity had it's own ID and own table. The other classes always existed and my mappings worked fine. Here are my classes:

```
public abstract class Entity
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; } 
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
        public EntityStatus EntityStatus { get; set; }
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }


    public abstract class ContextEntity : Entity
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual Contact Owner { get; set; }
    }


    public abstract class Document : ContextEntity
    {

        public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }

    }

    //This is the Class I want as a table
    public class Rfi : Document
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }

    }
```

Before I had the ContextEntity I only had Entity. Not all my entities will use the ContextEntity. I have this mapping file:

```
public class EntityConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : Entity
    {
        protected EntityConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(e => e.Id);

            Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(e => e.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
        }
    }
```

When I just had the Entity base type it worked great. So I thought I would add another configuration mapper like this:

```
public class ContextEntityConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
        where TEntity : ContextEntity
    {
        protected BridgeEntityConfiguration()
        {

            HasKey(e => e.Id);

            Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(e => e.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
            HasMany(e => e.Comments).WithMany().Map(m =>
                                                        {
                                                            m.MapLeftKey("CommentId");
                                                            m.MapRightKey("EntityId");
                                                            m.ToTable("Entity_Comments");
                                                        });
            HasMany(e => e.Attachments).WithMany().Map(m =>
                                                           {
                                                               m.MapLeftKey("AttachmentId");
                                                               m.MapRightKey("EntityId");
                                                               m.ToTable("Entity_Attachments");
                                                           });
        }
    }
```

My Derive mapping class looks like this:

```
RfiMapping: ContextEntityConfiguration<Rfi>
```

I am guessing EF doesn't know what to do with all the nested base classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the Subscription property in my Document class. In that class was a property that needed to be null-able. Once I added the mapping for the Subscription class and updated the null able property everything worked fine. Not sure why it was giving me an error on my Rfi class, but the issue was not in that class.

Comment: I'm frustrated. If this is the only change you have done to the code you've shown in your question, I really cannot understand how this could fix your exception *"The property 'Id' is not a declared property on type..."*. There is still the line `HasKey(e => e.Id)` in your `ContextEntityConfiguration<TEntity>` and `EntityConfiguration<TEntity>` and still no `Id` property declared on the `Rfi` class. I don't understand how this could work if `TEntity` is `Rfi`. Never mind, somehow it seems to work now as you say.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot derive `RfiMapping` from `ContextEntityConfiguration<Rfi>`. This would mean that you are trying to configure - for example - the `Id` property on your `Rfi` class. When added to the model configurations it basically reads like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Rfi>()
    .HasKey(r => r.Id);
// etc.
```

But `Id` is **declared** on the base class `Entity`, so you cannot define mappings for such a property on your derived entity. That's what the exception says.

If you want to define mappings on base class properties you must also use this class in your mapping configuration:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
    .HasKey(r => r.Id);
// etc.
```

I believe that a generic configuration derived from `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` is a bad idea. The derived configuration classes should always deal with one specific entity (can also be an abstract entity) and define the mappings for it.

So, you should have the following configurations:

```cs
public class EntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
public class ContextEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContextEntity>
public class DocumentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Document>
public class RfiConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Rfi>
```

**Edit**

Here is an example application that shows that it also cannot work with your old mapping (without `ContextEntity`). You can test and compare with the differences to your real model. There must be some important difference because you say that your old model works. I have omitted a few scalar properties to make the example simpler.

- Create new .NET 4 console application in VS2010
- Add reference to `EntityFramework.dll`
- Delete content of `Program.cs` and paste in the following
- Run application (it will crash)

->

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace EFWrongMapping
{
    public abstract class Entity
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Document : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rfi : Document
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
    }

    public class EntityConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
        where TEntity : Entity
    {
        protected EntityConfiguration()
        {
            // The following is not allowed if TEntity is Rfi or generally any other
            // type than Entity (which makes it useless to create a generic configuration)
            HasKey(e => e.Id);
            Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }

    public class RfiMapping : EntityConfiguration<Rfi>
    {
        public RfiMapping()
        {
        }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RfiMapping());
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                // just try to build model and initialize DB
                var initializer = new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>();
                try
                {
                    initializer.InitializeDatabase(context);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We will land here with exception:
                    // "The property 'Id' is not a declared property on type 'Rfi'"
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I said above, before I added the ContextEntity and the Configuration class for it, everything worked fine. Why is having a generic configuration class bad?

Comment: Also, wouldn't having the separate config files create separate tables?

Comment: @DDiVita: Because it leads to the exception you have now :) Like I (and the exception) said, you must define property mappings on the entity where the property is **declared** in. If your former code had the `Id` property also on the `Entity` class and not in the `Rfi` class, and your mapping was like `RfiMapping: EntityConfiguration<Rfi>` I cannot believe that you didn't get the same exception. (It's exactly the same situation the exception is complaining about). There must be another important difference between your old and new code.

Comment: @DDiVita: No, the configuration classes are just related to each entity. What tables you get depends on your actual mapping code. In your case I'd expect TPH mapping: `Entity`, `ContextEntity`, `Document` and `Rfi` are all stored in the same single table. TPH is default inheritance mapping in EF 4.1 and I don't see any calls of `ToTable` (TPT mapping) or `MapInheritedProperties` (TPC mapping) which would overwrite this default.

Comment: If you replace Document: ContextEntity with Doument: Entity and RfiMapping: ContextEntityConfiguration<Rfi> with RfiMapping: EntityConfiguration  it works great. Once I add the additional ContextEntity class, it fails.

Comment: @DDiVita: I've just tested with: `RfiMapping : EntityConfiguration<Rfi>` and your `EntityConfiguration<TEntity>` code in the question. I get the expected exception "*Id is not a declared property on type Rfi*". There must be another difference.

Comment: @Slauma let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2815/discussion-between-ddivita-and-slauma)

Comment: Well, that is very similar to my original code and that works for me. I figured out what my issue was. See my answer.

Comment: The difference will be that @Slauma uses `DbSet<Entity>` instead of `DbSet<Rfi>`. The question is wrong in the main point - this is not TPC inheritance mapping.

Comment: I just tested with @Ladislav's correction to replace `DbSet<Entity>` in my example by `DbSet<Rfi>` (so that `Entity` is not an entity in the model anymore): The exception disappears now.