# Change data type of properties inherited from the base class in Entity Framework 5 code first

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am working on an application that uses EF 5 Code First against a SQL Server database. Some of my domain objects inherit from the base abstract class `DomainEntity` that contains shared properties, such as `Id`, `DateCreated`, `DateModified`, etc.

By default EF creates `datetime` columns for properties of type `DateTime`. I have been looking for a way to tell it to create `smalldatetime` columns instead for all subclasses of `DomainEntity`.

I've tried the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Ignore<DomainEntity>();   
    modelBuilder.Entity<DomainEntity>()
        .Property(e => e.DateCreated).HasColumnType("smalldatetime"); 
}
```

Unfortunately the above has no effect. And if I remove the `Ignore<DomainEntity>` line then EF creates a separate table called `DomainEntities`.

The only approach that seems to work is to explicitly map `DateTime` properties in each subclass of `DomainEntity`, but obviously it is impractical because I have a couple of dozen of such classes.

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all?

---

### UPDATE

It works when I decorate the base class' date properties with the data annotation         `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(TypeName="smalldatetime")]`.

Although I would really prefer to keep this DB-specific mapping information in the EF context and out of my POCO's.

Comment: You gonna like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15579971/861716)

Comment: Thanks Gert, it is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: OK, great! I marked your question as duplicate. Don't worry, that's not a bad thing. Your question will serve as a signpost and this way we all prevent clutter and scattering of answers.

Comment: Cheers simply decorating POCOS with a [Column(TypeName="smalldatetime")] sounds like a nice clean solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I specify global mapping rules in Entity Framework Code First?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578528/can-i-specify-global-mapping-rules-in-entity-framework-code-first)