# Code First Entity Framework: Foreign key problems

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am trying to build a system that maintains a three way relationship. But when I am entering the second instance of a relationship I am getting an exception.

Here is the basic code

```
public class Role
{
    protected Role() { }

    public Role(string id, string description) : this()
    {
        Id = id;
        Description = description;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid EntityId { get; private set; }
}

public class Project : Entity
{
    protected Project()
    {
        UserProjectRoles = new Collection<UserProjectRole>();
    }

    public Project(string id, string description, string connectionString)
    {
        Id = id;
        Description = description;
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProjectRole> UserProjectRoles { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get { return UserProjectRoles.Select(x => x.User).Distinct(); } }
}

public class User : Entity
{
    protected User()
    {
        UserProjectRoles = new Collection<UserProjectRole>();
    }

    public User(string uniqueName)
        : this()
    {
        UniqueName = uniqueName;
    }

    public string UniqueName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProjectRole> UserProjectRoles { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects { get { return UserProjectRoles.Select(x => x.Project).Distinct(); } }
}

public class UserProjectRole
{
    protected UserProjectRole() { }

    public UserProjectRole(Project project, User user, Role role)
    {
        Project = project;
        User = user;
        Role = role;
    }

    public Guid ProjectId { get; private set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; private set; }
    public string RoleId { get; private set; }

    public Project Project { get; private set; }
    public User User { get; private set; }
    public Role Role { get; private set; }
}

public class MasterContext : DbContext
{
    public MasterContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().HasKey(e => e.EntityId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(e => e.EntityId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Map(u => u.MapInheritedProperties()).ToTable("Projects");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(p => p.MapInheritedProperties()).ToTable("Users");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasKey(r => r.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProjectRole>().HasKey(x => new { x.ProjectId, x.UserId, x.RoleId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProjectRole>().HasRequired(x => x.User).WithMany(u => u.UserProjectRoles).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProjectRole>().HasRequired(x => x.Project).WithMany(p => p.UserProjectRoles).HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProjectRole>().HasRequired(x => x.Role).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

And here is a test case that demonstrates the error.

```
[TestFixture]
public class EFTest
{
    private const string MasterConnectionString =
        "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TheDatabase;Integrated Security=True;";

    private static readonly Role DataCollector = new Role("1", "Data Collector");
    private static readonly Role Manager = new Role("2", "Manager");

    [Test]
    public void TheTest()
    {

        var user = new User("Tim the Enchanter");
        var project = new Project("Foo", "Bar", "Another Connection string");

        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MasterContext>());
        using (var masterContext = new MasterContext(MasterConnectionString))
        {
            user.UserProjectRoles.Add(new UserProjectRole(project, user, DataCollector));
            masterContext.Users.Add(user);
            masterContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MasterContext>());
        using (var masterContext = new MasterContext(MasterConnectionString))
        {
            var u = masterContext.Users.First();
            var p = u.Projects.First();
            u.UserProjectRoles.Add(new UserProjectRole(p, u, Manager));

            masterContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run that test I get the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : An error
>   occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details.   ----> System.Data.UpdateException : An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.   ---->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.UserProjectRoles_dbo.Projects_ProjectId". The conflict
>   occurred in database "Dev_Local_Master", table "dbo.Projects", column
>   'EntityId'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: At which line do you get the error?

Comment: The second SaveChanges() call throws the exception.

Comment: What happens if you remove the two lines with `modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()` and do the configuration of `Entity` by data annotations? (The effect is that `Entity` is not known to the EF model).

Comment: I am specifically avoiding using the data annotations. I don't want the business POCO objects to know about the persistance layer.

Comment: I understand. It was just for trying, because I've noticed that an EF model with a base type usually is better off not knowing about the base type, only the derived types. Data annotations is a quick way to achieve that. If it helped there would have been a [way to do it without data annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15579971/861716), but that takes some more work.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the User, Project, and Role on UserProjectRole all needed to be virtual for it to work properly.

The error messages were somewhat less than helpful in figuring this out.