# Entity Framework TPC abstract identity issue

Tags: entity-framework, table-per-class

Came across a most odd error during model generation.

Apparently, the following is allowed:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
   public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
   public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
   public int CarId { get; set; }
}
```

But this isn't allowed:

```
public abstract class ReferenceEntity : Entity
{
}

public class CarType : ReferenceEntity
{
   public int CarTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

I will receive the following error:
ReferenceEntities: EntityType: EntitySet 'ReferenceEntities' is based on type 'ReferenceEntity' that has no keys defined.

Neither abstract class defines a key, I leave that up to each concrete class. I was trying to get around the TPC issue where identity problems arise when the identity key is placed in an abstract class when ids are automatically generated by the DB.

Help?

Another question. For my abstract classes, am I allowed to specify EntityTypeConfigurations? This is using Entity Framework 6.

Comment: Often it works much better to leave EF ignorant of such base classes. You won't have all these inheritance complications if you only map the derived classes. Maybe a trick like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15579971/861716) cam help you implement this.

Comment: In your example, you have a BaseMapping configuration. What if I wanted to extend that further with another configuration where the type inherits from BaseEntity?

Comment: You could have an inheritance hierarchy like `BaseReferenceMapping<T> : BaseMapping<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` if that's what you mean.

Comment: Exactly what I mean. Would I need to use the "where" keyword?

Do you have an example somewhere?

Comment: If you want to map properties like `CreatedBy`, yes.

Comment: Gert, I want to thank you again - so thankful for your assistance and direction.

Good day to you sir. **salutes**