# The entity type EntityBase is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF 6 and have following

```
public class Title : EntityBase
{

    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleName { get; private set; }

}
 public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

And DbContext contains

```
public DbSet<Title> Titles { get; set; }
```

and also

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Title>().Map(m =>
       {
           m.MapInheritedProperties();
           m.ToTable("Titles");
       });
```

But while trying to access Titles, I get "The entity type EntityBase is not part of the model for the current context." After I run  Update-Database in NuGet console, I see that table 'Titles' is created in database  with all fields (id,titlename, createddate) as expected. I don't want to add EntityBase db set in DbContext if possible. Kindly help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MapInheritedProperties` is used to model a table-per-concrete type (TPC) mapping, a complete table for each class. You can do this, but then you have to configure the base class as well.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityBase>();
```

However, I'd rather remove the `MapInheritedProperties` statement and map each class individually. If you map a TPC mapping you'll never be able to map other inheritance associations between other classes of your model.

Comment: Thanks, but If I include EntityBase, I need to define key field which I don't want to do in base class. Even if I move Id field to EntityBase and try updating db, it throws "The type 'Title' cannot be mapped as defined because it maps inherited properties from types that use entity splitting or another form of inheritance. Either choose a different inheritance mapping strategy so as to not map inherited properties, or change all types in the hierarchy to map inherited properties and to not use splitting. ".

Comment: I also tried removing abstract modifier in EntityBase but no help. My requirement is TPC in some but mostly TPT inheriting from EntityBase. Is it not possible?

Comment: What id you remove the `MapInheritedProperties` statement as I suggested? You classes can inherit from other classes but EF doesn't need to know this.

Comment: I tried that one too which brings back to square one again "The entity type EntityBase is not part of the model for the current context." I simply removed  m.MapInheritedProperties(); from my example above. Update-Database does work and db schema is fine. Issue occurs while accessing DbSet.

Comment: I can use your classes in a sample project, not tell EF about the base class and create titles. I think something else is wrong that I can't see.

Comment: Hi Gert, thanks, you are right, it works. I will find whats wrong in my existing project.. may be error is coming from somewhere else. Sorry that I did not test it first in an empty project. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No sweat. Maybe one last thing that could help keeping the abstract class away from EF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15579971/861716