# Entity Framework 6.1 Code First TPH/TPT hybrid mapping issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, table-per-type, table-per-hierarchy, entity-framework-6.1

I have a model where most of the entities inherit the same base functionality. That functionality is encapsulated in an abstract base class. Above that, there are two branches of functionality and thus there are two abstract classes that inherit from the abstract base class. At this point, concrete classes inherit from their respective intermediate abstract classes.

Below is an example of the classes and EF mapping for one branch of this type of model model:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Base> Bases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Intermediate> Intermediates { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Intermediate>().ToTable("Concretes");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Concrete1>().ToTable("Concretes");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Concrete2>().ToTable("Concretes");
    }
}
public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BaseString { get; set; }
    public int BaseInteger { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Intermediate : Base
{
    public string IntermediateString { get; set; }
    public int IntermediateInteger { get; set; }
}

public class Concrete1 : Intermediate
{
    public string Concrete1String { get; set; }
    public int Concrete1Integer { get; set; }
}

public class Concrete2 : Intermediate
{
    public string Concrete2String { get; set; }
    public int Concrete2Integer { get; set; }
}
```

Where I am running into issues is with the table mapping. While mapping `Intermediate`, `Concrete1`, and `Concrete2` does generate a database- and even gives me a discriminator column- it does not make the columns nullable as is required for TPH mapping and therefore I end up with the following exception message:

> (28,10) : error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 28:Column Concretes.Concrete1Integer in table Concretes must be mapped: It has no default value and is not nullable.

I've tried several permutations of this-

- Only mapping `Intermediate` to a custom table- works, but the concrete types' fields are mapped to the "Bases" table.
- Mapping `Intermediate` to its own table and `Concrete1` & `Concrete2` to a table named "Concretes"- Exact same issues as the original mapping in the code example above.
- Mapping every entity to it's own table - This works, but it's purely TPT which isn't what I want.
- Mapping nothing- this puts everything in the "Bases" table and is purely TPH, which for the real results in an unacceptably wide and sparse table.

Is there not some way to get the mapping I'm looking for in the code example? That is, a "Bases" table and a "Concretes" table that uses a discriminator?

Comment: Did you consider the option to only map the concrete types, i.e. let EF be ignorant of the base types?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work for the real model we're using. Even if it did, that's a lot of redundant fields. TPC is usually discouraged unless you're working with an existing DB that forces you to use it, or you've got a really good/strange reason.

Comment: Lot of redundant fields... you can still have the inheritance, but just don't tell EF, so the common fields are still in a base type. Doing that, it helps a lot to have inherited mapping classes, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15579971/861716). Maybe you can leave the `Base` class out of the EF model and only map `Intermediate` and it's pendants as TPH or TPT.

Comment: I started a Codeplex issue and it seems that I've found another bug. I'll answer appropriately when I'm sure: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version Entity Framework 6.1.0, this is an outstanding bug. It sounds like it will be a bug in 6.1.1 as well, but [a fix has been scheduled for 6.1.2.](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2254)

Comment: Hi, i have a question about mapping TPT here, didn't find answer. could you look at a glance?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680633/map-tpt-strategy-entity-framework-code-fist

Comment: A fix for this has now been checked in and should be available in tomorrow's nightly build and in the upcoming 6.1.2 release.