# Map TPT Strategy Entity Framework Code fist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

Im working on EF Code first, I like abstraction! so want have ItemCat entity like this:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

public abstract  class TreeBase : EntityBase
    {
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual TreeBase Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TreeBase> Children { get; set; }

    }

public  abstract class CatBase : TreeBase
    {

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }


        public int OrderId { get; set; }

    }

public class ItemCat : CatBase
    {
        public stringName { get; set; }

// other fields...
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }
```

My map startgey is table per type.TPT

All base classes for ItemCat are decoreated by abstract keyword. but in Migration i get TreeBases Table in Db, really why? i'm wonder because it's abstract. does my mapping need define any configuration explicitly? im using EF 6

**Edit** also EF in Migration create Discriminator column for TreeBase table and when i insert Record it has ItemCat value.

**Edit**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
        {
            //Item

            mb.Configurations.Add(new TreeBaseConfig());
            mb.Configurations.Add(new CatConfig());

        }

 public class TreeBaseConfig:EntityTypeConfiguration<TreeBase>
    {
        public TreeBaseConfig()
        {
            HasMany(rs => rs.Children).WithOptional(rs => rs.Parent).HasForeignKey(rs => rs.ParentId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

public  class CatConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<CatBase>
    {
        public CatConfig()
        {
            //properties
            Property(rs => rs.Name).IsUnicode();
            Property(rs => rs.ImageUrl).IsUnicode();
            Property(rs => rs.Description).IsUnicode();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

I added ItemCatConfig Class:

```
public ItemCatConfig()
    {

        //map
       Map(m =>  { m.ToTable("ItemCats"); m.MapInheritedProperties(); });
    }
```

but get:

> The type 'ItemCat' cannot be mapped as defined because it maps
>   inherited properties from types that use entity splitting or another
>   form of inheritance. Either choose a different inheritance mapping
>   strategy so as to not map inherited properties, or change all types in
>   the hierarchy to map inherited properties and to not use splitting.

Comment: can you post your derived DbContext class's code, or at least the OnModelCreating method?

Comment: Hi @joelmdev yes , why not

Comment: Do you have any idea, i'm confused, what the problem mayby is?

Comment: imho the "problem" is EF default strategy is TPH. If you want to enable TPT you have to explicitly configure table names for the types.

Comment: have you a `ToTable("Cats")` in your ItemCatConfig ?

Comment: Yes, look at my last Edit paragraph @tschmit007

Comment: do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) when you don't do any `ToTable()` mapping, and TPC (Table Per Concrete Type) when doing both `ToTable()` and `MapInheritedProperties()`. If you want to use TPT (Table Per Type) do only the `ToTable()` mapping and leave the call to `MapInheritedProperties()` off, like so:

```
ToTable("ItemCats");
```

Comment: Ok, now it create itemCat and TreeBase Tables with owns prop. i just want ItemCat

Comment: when i use TPC have to Map all base prop in last Concreat type: it mean must delete catConfig and use it's map in ItemCatConfig?

Comment: I highly recommend you read this series so you can figure out what mapping strategy you actually want: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx