# TPC mapping: MapInheritedProperties() force key inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6

The problem is that the PK of child is the parent's key, inspite of we have modified (Table per Class mapping used).

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }    
}

public class VersionedEntity: Entity
{
    public Guid VersionId { get; set; }    
}
```

OnModelCreating contains:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VersionedEntity>().Map(m =>
{
   m.MapInheritedProperties();
});
modelBuilder.Entity<VersionedEntity>().HasKey(e => new { e.EntityId , e.HistoryId});
```

As a result we will get VersionedEntity that still contains one-column PK (EntityId).

Do we have the possibility after m.MapInheritedProperties() replace/remove "inhereted" parent keys mappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you haven't. The reason is that EF has one entity key definition for the whole inheritance tree. In my opinion it should even throw an error for the second `HasKey` statement, instead of silently ignoring it.

The reason for having one entity key definition is that you *might* (but probably don't) expose all entities by one `DbSet<Entity>`. If so, it should be possible to do...

```
context.Entities.Find(Guid.Parse(someGuid));
```

This is impossible if one subtype has a different type of key.

If you need to hang on to this model, you better keep EF oblivious of the base class and map each type separately, without a mapped inheritance. It may help to have a [base `EntityTypeConfiguration`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579971/861716) in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you. I'm ok with your answer but unfortunatly I miss something important in you explanation. I want to keep one key, there is no need to explain me why I need one key. But I was interested in the possibility to access the structures where we save "key definitions" and remove "inherited key" from that structure.

Comment: OK, that's slightly different. I guess technically, two classes in a TPC inheritance could have different key field names, as long as the number, the order and the types of the fields match exactly. EF just doesn't support that. I can't imagine how keys with a variable number of fields could fit into one inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: As you see on the structures level two keys fits (I can create second). So that what I've searched for: to find the "keys" array that should be located somewhere deep in the modelBuilder and remove one key that is associated with child entity (that was created on  MapInheritedProperties ). Then I will be able to create new key. Does it makes sense?

Comment: Frankly, no. EF should always be able to identify *all* object instances of derived classes by the same unique key. If you'd be able to somehow add a second key property, the `EntityId` values could get duplicated and EF would throw a duplicate key exception. Your case just isn't implemented. *Maybe* EF could compare key values per type in TPC - but it doesn't.

Comment: Friend, I do not want to create second key for the child entity, I want to REPLACE the one that is created by MapInheritedProperties with the new. You now: somewhere there is the dictioanary: table-key; MapInheritedProperties  adds to this dictioanary the pair that I want to remove. That is so simple... But I could wrong that this is possible.

Comment: All I know is `HasKey(e => new { e.EntityId , e.HistoryId})`

Comment: @GertArnold Did you found solution to this problem? Scenario with Object -> ObjectHistory is fairly common, I can't believe the EF can't solve it.