# Entity Framework relationship with two foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I'm having a problem with connecting two tables in FluentAPI. It's in fact a mix of FluentAPI and Data Annotations. I Looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523121/how-to-add-a-composite-unique-key-using-ef-6-fluent-api) but It didn't help me. I tried with `Index`, composed unique keys.

Basically `Foo` is the main table. `Bar` table is optional. The are connected via two columns. `key1` and `key2` pairs are unique. Think of it as a parent-child relationship with a restriction that 1 parent can have only 1 child:

Data Entities looks like this:

```
[Table("foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    [Column("pk", TypeName = "int")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    [Column("key1", TypeName = "int")]
    public int Key1 { get; set; }
    [Column("key2", TypeName = "int")]
    public int Key2 { get; set; }

    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

[Table("bar")]
public class Bar
{
    [Key]
    [Column("key1", TypeName = "int", Order = 1)]
    public int Key1 { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column("key2", TypeName = "int", Order = 2)]
    public int Key2 { get; set; }

    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I was trying to connect them:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasRequired(p => p.Foo).WithOptional(p => p.Bar);
```

What is wrong?
`Bar` DOES require `Foo`. `Foo` DOES have optional `Bar`. <--- this should be totally enough, because `Foo` has columns named exactly like primary keys in `Bar`. But it doesn't work.

So I tried specifying foreign keys:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasRequired(p => p.Foo).WithOptional(p => p.Bar).Map(p => p.MapKey(new[] { "key1", "key2" }));
```

It says:

> "The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key
>   columns"

Whaaaat? how? how come? Uhh..

I also tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasIndex(table => new { table.Key1, table.Key2 });
```

So my questions are:

1. Why my solution doesn't work? I do have complex key specified
2. How can I slove it?

Comment: It's the opposite of what you are assuming. `Foo` is *required*, `Bar` is *optional*, hence `Foo` is the *principal* (parent) and `Bar` is the *dependent* (child), so `Bar` should have FK pointing to `Foo`s PK.

Comment: In EF6, you can only refer to other entities by primary key, so both entities should share `FooId`, you simply can't use `Key1` and `Key2`.

Comment: @GertArnold wait wait wait.. so you're saying that I should add `FooId` column to the `Bar` table? Because it that case I'm not sure if I will be able to create a FK in the database?

Comment: Well, its name can be anything, but it should be a [shared primary key association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations).

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a little complicated, and I might be completely wrong here, but from my experience EntityFramework relations don't work that way. It seems to me that if Foo is *required* and Bar is *optional*, then each Bar should have a way to join back to Foo uniquely based upon Foo's *pk* value.

That is to say that Bar should be defined as:

```
[Table("bar")]
public class Bar
{
    [Key]
    [Column("key1", TypeName = "int", Order = 1)]
    public int Key1 { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column("key2", TypeName = "int", Order = 2)]
    public int Key2 { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

You would then need to use this FooId in your description of the relationship, not the composite key contained in Bar. EntityFramework has always required me to join on the entire primary key of the parent POCO, which must be a foreign key of the child POCO. You may still be able to join through the child's key in LINQ queries.