# Unable to determine composite primary key ordering

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the given EF entity.

```
    [Key]
    [Column("ACTIVITY.ID", Order = 0)]
    public string ActivityId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("STATISTIC.SECTION", Order = 1)]
    public string StatisticSection { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("STATISTIC.NAME", Order = 2)]
    public string StatisticName { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("LAP.ID", Order = 3)]
    public string LapId { get; set; }

    [Column("STATISTIC.TYPE")]
    public string StatisticType { get; set; }

    [Column("STATISTIC.VALUE")]
    public string StatisticValue { get; set; }

    [Column("STATISTIC.UNIT")]
    public string StatisticUnit { get; set; }
```

and when doing an insert operation using the method bellow:

```
    public bool Add(ICollection<RefLapStatistic> entities)
    {
        return HandleInsert(() =>
        {
            using (var context = new ReportingRefDataContext(DataSource))
            {
                var activities = entities.Select(x => x.ActivityId).Distinct();
                var entitiesToDelete = context.LapStatistics
                .Where(x => activities.Any(y => x.ActivityId.Equals(y, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

                context.LapStatistics.RemoveRange(entitiesToDelete);

                entities.ToList().ForEach(x => context.LapStatistics.Add(Mapper.Map< RefLapStatisticEntity>(x)));

                return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
            }
        });
    }
```

I get the following error when executing the line bellow:

```
var entitiesToDelete = context.LapStatistics
                .Where(x => activities.Any(y => x.ActivityId.Equals(y, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

> Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type

I have no idea why this is happening, can't see any issues with the mapping and the exception is being raised even before the Save method. This issue has nothing to do with missing the Ordering attribute has I've have that defined.

Comment: Are you sure you are using EF6?

Comment: What .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: Yes I am sure (6.1.3), 4.5.2. I have many other mappings working just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping composite keys using EF code first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792295/mapping-composite-keys-using-ef-code-first)

Comment: @demo, my issue is different, I do have the column ordering set.

Comment: Can you check where -> var entitiesToDelete = context.LapStatistics
                    .Where(x => x.ActivityId !=null); or a simpler query working?

Comment: context.LapStatistics.Add(Mapper.Map< RefLapStatisticEntity>(x) It fails here as well.

Comment: Are the properties of your entity mapped to columns from different tables?

Comment: No they are all mapped to the same table, but this problem is happening even before the EF tries to execute the code against the database

Comment: Not really. It happens before you call `SaveChanges`, but before that, you're querying the db for `Activities`, which might be where the problem lies.

Comment: Yes you right, but if I comment that code if fails when adding the tables to the context.

Comment: I'm also confused about your column names, as I don't think SQL server column names can contain `.`'s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105814/discussion-between-rik-and-marco).

Comment: @Rik the problem was related to some other entity in the context... thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you explain? I am having similar issues and not finding answers. I have the ColumnAttribute defined with correct orders.