# Table per Concrete Type(TPC) mapping with Composite key in the EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, composite-key

I have an table hierarchy with Table per Concrete Type (TPC) mapping.
(I not sure that [Key, Column] attribute are necessary but according https://stackoverflow.com/a/19792915/959779 it's should work)

Class structure:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Page: BaseEntity {
    string Data { get; set; }
}
public class PageBackup: Page {
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
}
```

When`Id` of the `Page` and `PageBackup` entities are intersect(after adding to tables some items) EF throw the next excution

> "All objects in the EntitySet 'EUICDataContext.Pages' must have unique primary keys.
>   However, an instance of type 'Entities.PageBackup' and an instance of type 
>   'Entities.Page' both have the same primary key value, 'EntitySet=Pages;Id=6'. "

Entities mapping code below:

```
class PageMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Page> 
{
    public PageMapping ()
    {
        Map(m =>{ m.ToTable("Page"); });
        HasKey(t => t.Id });
    }
}

class PageBackupMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<PageBackup> 
{
    public PageBackupMapping ()
    {
        Map(m =>{
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("PageBackup");
        });
        HasKey(t => new { t.Id, t.PageId });
    }
 }
```

The problem is although in the EF `PageMapping` has composite key `Update-Database` seed script creates table with the next signature:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PageBackup](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PageId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.PageBackup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
            [Id] ASC
    )
```

Is EF allows to create tables with composite keys(lot of examples with mapping but I didn't found any about the migrations)?

And how to describe such configuration on behalf of TPC mapping?

Any other solution proposal will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm playing with it, it looks like this is case is not supported by the EF 6. My migration automatically generated with Id primary key.

```
  CreateTable(
            "dbo.PageBackUp",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PageId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

After that I've try to manage this one on EF Core 1.1.0 . I got an error in that case

> A key cannot be configured on 'Page' because it is a derived type. The
>   key must be configured on the root type 'BaseEntity'. If you did not
>   intend for 'BaseEntity' to be included in the model, ensure that it is
>   not included in a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a
>   configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation
>   property on a type that is included in the model.

I think this is a limitation of the Entity Framework. You can raise an issue to the [EF repo](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) with this question.

My EF Core configuration was:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext()
    {

    }
    public ProductContext(DbContextOptions<ProductContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Page> Page { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PageBackup> PageBackup { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;");
        base.OnConfiguring(builder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Page>()
            .HasBaseType<BaseEntity>()
            .ToTable("Page")
            .HasKey(t => t.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PageBackup>()
            .HasBaseType<Page>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PageId, t.Id });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

EF 6 version:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Page> Page { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PageBackup> PageBackup { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Page>()
            .Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties().ToTable("Page"))
            .HasKey(t => t.Id);


        modelBuilder.Entity<PageBackup>()
            .Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties().ToTable("PageBackUp"))
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PageId, t.Id });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```