# EF Core how add Primary Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this class definition into Ef Core Model for SQLite.

```
public class Ejercicios : BaseModel
{
    private int _TipoEjercicio;
    [Key]
    public int TipoEjercicio
    {
        get { return _TipoEjercicio; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _TipoEjercicio, value); }
    }

    private string _DescripcionEjercicio;
    public string DescripcionEjercicio
    {
        get { return _DescripcionEjercicio; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _DescripcionEjercicio, value); }
    }

    private string _HexForeColor;
    public string HexForeColor
    {
        get { return _HexForeColor; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _HexForeColor, value); }
    }

    private string _HexBackGroundColor;
    public string HexBackGroundColor
    {
        get { return _HexBackGroundColor; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _HexBackGroundColor, value); }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when I try to run **Add-Migration**, throws

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Ejercicios' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

How to add primary key to an EF Core Model for sqlite ?

**Edit 1:** Model Generator

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Ejercicios> Ejercicios { get; set; }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=MyDb.db");
    }
}
```

Comment: For EF 7 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75425849/6527049

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you use [fluent api](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_fluent_api.htm) ?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ejercicios>()
    .HasKey(p => new p.TipoEjercicio);
```

Try this out, i think your problem is now solved.

**---Update---**

Create Your `DbContext` First:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("name=MyConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, YourApplication.Migrations.Configuration>("MyConnection")); 
    }
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //here you can MAP Your Models/Entities, but i am going to show you something more interesting. so keep up. 
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UsersMap());
    }
}
```

Create a Migration Folder in your app root And make `Configuration` class there:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourApplication.Infrastructure.Data.MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        ContextKey = "YourApplication.Infrastructure.Data.MyDbContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(YourApplication.Infrastructure.Data.MyDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

I am a Germ Freak, so i write my codes very clean. That's why when for example i made a `Model` like below, i create an `EntityBase` for every `Id`:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And Implement it to my `Model` :

```
public class User: EntityBase
{
    public string Example1{ get; set; }
    public string Example2{ get; set; }
    public string Example3{ get; set; }
}
```

And For Mapping I Create another Class like below and use `Fluent Api`:

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        ToTable("TblUser");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Example1)
            .IsRequired();
        //etc

    }
}
```

But if you don't want to go through all the trouble you can easily just insert the fluent api in your `DbContext's OnModelCreating` Method Like i said at start. By the way be aware if you are using fluent api, you Shouldn't use Data Annotations. Happy Coding.

Comment: Where must add this code ? I was trying at model generator but can't found a method named **OnModelCreating.** to override it

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez are you using EF Code-First?

Comment: I'm going to post my Model Generator.

Comment: At **EF Core**  Documentation I must build my db using **Add-Migration** really I don't know if this is a code first approach. But my model was based on classes writed by me.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez anytime mate, happy to help

Comment: Only a Little question do you know why Annotations doesn't work  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131614/discussion-between-valkyriee-and-juan-pablo-gomez).

Answer (score 2):

If you use EF core add

```
 .UseSerialColumn();
```

Example

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobItem>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("jobs");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("id")
                .UseSerialColumn();
});
```

Im using EF.postgres