# same key value for is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ProjectAssignment' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ProjectID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.St
```

I made a project with Worker (ID and other columns) And Project (ID and other columns) Entity and ProjectAssignment (many Project ID to many Workers) Crossbound. But error in Application Insights appears when I try to fetch ProjectAssignment data. Strange that id does not appear earlier.

Here it is https://github.com/Streamc/ContosoObserve1/tree/master/Proj_s

```
 context.Database.EnsureCreated();

  var ProjectAssignments = new ProjectAssignment[]
             {
                    new ProjectAssignment
                    {
                        ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID,
                        WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID,
                    },
                     new ProjectAssignment
                    {
                        ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID,
                        WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 2).ID,
                    },
                     new ProjectAssignment
                    {
                        ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID,
                        WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 3).ID,
                    },
                    new ProjectAssignment
                    {
                        ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 2).ID,
                        WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID,
                    },
                    new ProjectAssignment
                    {
                        ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 3).ID,
                        WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID,
                    },
                    new ProjectAssignment
                    {
                        ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 4).ID,
                        WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID,
                    },
                    new ProjectAssignment
                    {
                        ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 2).ID,
                        WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 2).ID,
                    },
                    new ProjectAssignment
                    {
                        ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 2).ID,
                        WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 3).ID,
                    },
                    new ProjectAssignment
                    {
                        ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 2).ID,
                        WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 4).ID,
                    }

             };
            foreach (ProjectAssignment ss in ProjectAssignments)
            {
                context.ProjectAssignments.Add(ss);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();



 public class ProjectAssignment
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public int WorkerID { get; set; }


        public Project Project { get; set; }
        public Worker Worker { get; set; }

    }
   public class Worker
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Fathername { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }    
        public string Company_name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProjectAssignment> ProjectAssignment { get; set; }

    }
    public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Customer_Company { get; set; }
        public string Executive_Company { get; set; }
        public int ManagerID { get; set; }    
        public int WorkerID { get; set; }    
        public DateTime Begin_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime End_date { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }    
        public string Test_comment { get; set; }    
        public ICollection<ProjectAssignment> ProjectAssignment { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please show some code that reproduces this error. See [mcve] for tips on creating a good code example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read the error message carefully:

> The instance of entity type 'ProjectAssignment' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ProjectID'} is already being tracked.

So the problem is that we got two or more `ProjectAssignment` with the same `ProjectID`.

If we look at the code we see that we assign the same `ProjectID` twice:

```
 var ProjectAssignments = new ProjectAssignment[] {
     new ProjectAssignment {
         ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID, // ID == "1"
         WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID,
     },
     new ProjectAssignment {
         ProjectID = Projects.Single( i => i.ID == 1).ID, // ID == "1", again
         WorkerID = Workers.Single( i => i.ID == 2).ID,
     },
     // ...
 }
```

The root cause seems to be that `ProjectID` was modeled as Primary Key instead of as Foreign Key. Primary Keys must be unique. What you probably want is a [composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792295/mapping-composite-keys-using-ef-code-first) consisting of `ProjectID` and `WorkerID`.

Looking at the `ProjectContext` in your Github project, this composite key is already in place:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectAssignment>().HasKey(c => new { c.ProjectID, c.WorkerID });
```

But it conflicts with the `[Key]` annotation on `ProjectAssignment.ProjectID`. Remove this `[Key]` attribute!

Comment: I find it earlier. I repaired it.  Yes, logic is 2 column key. I just tested keyattribute and miss that I did not erase line. The problem is really in key attribute. Thanks for answer!

Comment: I thinks question should be deleted.