# EF not recognizing Column attribute for code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following class definition for a Code First entity:

```
public class Matches
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid MatchGroup { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public long ProcedureId { get; set; }

    public long MatchLevelId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProcedureId")]
    public virtual Procedure Procedure { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MatchLevelId")]
    public virtual ProcedureMatchLevel MatchLevel { get; set; }
}
```

However when creating my initial migration I get the following error:

```
Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type 
'Entities.Procedures' Use the ColumnAttribute or the HasKey 
method to specify an order for composite primary keys.
```

As you can see, I am using the `[Column]` attribute.

Has anyone ran into this issue before? I've tried switching which property my `[ForeignKey]` declaration is on, using `[Key, ForeignKey("Procedure")]` with the same error.

---

Procedures class:

```
[Table("ProcedureList")]
public class Procedure
{
    [Required]
    public int ProcedureId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does your DbContext class look like and your Procedure class look like?  I think that the problem may be in the Procedure class not the Matches class.

Comment: It does work if I use Fluent API (`modelBuilder.Entity<Matches>().HasKey(x => new { x.MatchGroup, x.ProcedureId });`, however I'm not using Fluent API for anything else so I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong with the Data Attributes to maintain some consistency.

Comment: Thanks @MikeWodarczyk, I will update with my procedure class momentarily.

Comment: The column order index begins at 0, are you sure your orders are 1 & 2 and not 0 & 1

Comment: In [this related or duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792295/mapping-composite-keys-using-ef-code-first) I see the Order is zero based index.

Comment: @Daniel It is zero index and you are correct I should use 0/1 and not 1/2; still get the error with these values, however.

Comment: Have you tried what @Daniel said?

Comment: @PhillipCopley look at procedure class, why you have no primary key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping composite keys using EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792295/mapping-composite-keys-using-ef-code-first)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft No, the `Order` of the composite key is present, your link is not duplicated but related. The problem is on the `Procedure` class, it should have a `[Key]` attribute but is missing and because of that the `Matches` class has a `[Foreign]` that "points to nowhere".

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the primary key for Procedure class as well

```
[Table("ProcedureList")]
public class Procedure
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ProcedureId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```