# Creating a composite key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace exmapleNameSpace.DTO
{
    public class Edges
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string NameEdge;
        [Required]
        public Item Neighbor_ID1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool ID1isFile { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Item Neighbor_ID2 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool ID2isFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Items model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace exampleNameSpace.DTO
{
    public class Item
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool isFolder { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool isFile { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"\w.([a - z]|[A-Z])")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string extension { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string parentPath { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool isEmpty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I currently have my index built keeping `ID` as primary key in both the entities. I have `Neighbor_ID1` and `Neighbor_ID2` as two foreign keys, however I want to make a composite key consisting of (`Neighbor_ID1, Neighbor_ID2`) for uniquely identifying edges.

Can I just add `[Key]` annotations for both and edit my up method to have `AddForeignKeyOperations()` ?

I am quite new to EF and would like to know the advantages or disadvantages of the approach.

PS: I understand that cascade delete operations with my current approach wouldn't work. Assume a connected acyclic graph topology in between the said Edges and Verteces and that I would want a many-to-many relationship ideally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping composite keys using EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792295/mapping-composite-keys-using-ef-code-first)

Comment: Have you considered using FluentApi?

Comment: Why should the question be closed, when the duplicate pointed to ,doesn't answer the question completely? @marc_s

Comment: The accepted answer clearly shows how to do this - why doesn't that answer your question??

Comment: "I am quite new to EF and would like to know the advantages or disadvantages of the approach. PS: I understand that cascade delete operations with my current approach wouldn't work. Assume a connected acyclic graph topology in between the said Edges and Verteces and that I would want a many-to-many relationship ideally" because i wanted to know what would happen in this scenario and if it would be a good idea in the first place @marc_s