# EntityType ' ' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. - C# Web API Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting the following error, even though I added the `[key]` attribute after reading about it on this forum:

> EntityType 'EbayItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Here is my `context` class:

```
public class PeopleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EbayItem> EbayItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EbayUser> EbayUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `EbayItem.cs`

```
[Table("tbl_items")]
public class EbayItem
{
    [key]
    public int Item_ID { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Bids { get; set; }

    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public EbayUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `EbayUser.cs`

```
[Table("tbl_users")]
public class EbayUser
{
    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }

    public IList<EbayItem> EbayItems { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `Get()`

```
// GET: api/Ebay
public IEnumerable<EbayItem> Get()
{
    PeopleContext context = new PeopleContext();
    List<EbayItem> items = context.EbayItems.Include(p => p.User).ToList();

    return items;
}
```

Here are screen grabs of my table designs:

[image: tnl_users]

[image: tbl_items]

Excuse the poor naming conventions as I'm just using this particular project as a playground to venture a but more deeper with Entity Framework.

Comment: I'm not seeing a [key] attribute on `EbayItem`, which is consistent with the error message.

Comment: I've edited my post, `[key]` is in the right place and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have 'Key' attribute with a capital letter? Or you can also specify column id name, like: [How to Specify Primary Key Name in EF-Code-First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607512/how-to-specify-primary-key-name-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: Ah!  No I had a lower case!  Mind you I have this error now `type failed to serialize the response body for content type` when I go to `api/ebay` but I imagine I'll have to post this question separately.

Comment: Yes, i think you should close this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you haven't defined a key for 'EbayItem' table. You can find more info here:

https://gilesey.wordpress.com/tag/entitytype-has-no-key-defined/

Remeber that you need to use the conventions for mapping tables properly if you don't want to use mapping attributes. Just add [key] on your EbayItem table property:

```
[Table("tbl_items")]
public class EbayItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Item_ID { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Bids { get; set; }

    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public EbayUser User { get; set; }
}
```

If you have problems mapping the relationships I recommend you to check the naming conventions OR is Fluent API for explicitly naming columns and relationships https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships

Comment: Hi, I've edited my post as the key was not in `EbayItem` but it is now.

Comment: @user1574598 I think this is related to poor naming conventions. I'd recommend you to improve names OR use Fluent API for explicitly naming the columns and relationships https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've got rid of the `Include(p => p.User).` and I am getting `xml` data back but with just an `user_id` instead of another list.

Comment: this is because you need at least two things. Changing Users property to virtual and improve the names if you want EF to map properly. Or as I told you before: using fluent API

Answer (score 0):

You should specify that `EbayItem.User_ID` is a foreign key for the `EbayItem.User` navigation property.  You can do this with the `ForeignKey` attribute.  Also use the virtual keyword on the navigation property.

```
[Table("tbl_items")]
public class EbayItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Item_ID { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Bids { get; set; }

    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User_ID")]
    public virtual EbayUser User { get; set; }
}
```