# Entity Framework 6 Custom DBConfiguration PK Constraint Name Generator

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Using MVC and Entity Framework 6 with Code First Migrations, EF out of box generates the PK Constraint names as dbo_TableName.  I want to be able to rename those to "pkTableColColumn"  I am aware that EF Core supports this`.HasConstraintName("MyFKConstraint");`

Unfortunately, I don't think EF 6 supports this through fluentAPI or data annotations.

I referenced [this amazing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099685/entity-framework-primary-key-constraint) as a starting point.  The major difference is that they wanted their PK constraint names to be "PKTable", where I would like mine to be named "pk[Table]Col[ColumnName]".

With a little changing of the PKNameGenerator class, mine ended up as follows:

```
public class PKNameGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    static readonly string PREFIX = "pk"; // prefix with pk

    // this one works as the Columns property exists in this context
    protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
    {
        createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.Name = GetPkName(createTableOperation.Name, createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.Columns);
        base.Generate(createTableOperation);
    }

    // this one works as the Columns property exists in this context
    protected override void Generate(AddPrimaryKeyOperation addPrimaryKeyOperation)
    {
        addPrimaryKeyOperation.Name = GetPkName(addPrimaryKeyOperation.Table, addPrimaryKeyOperation.Columns);
        base.Generate(addPrimaryKeyOperation);
    }

    // this one does not work as the Columns property does not exist in this context
    protected override void Generate(DropPrimaryKeyOperation dropPrimaryKeyOperation)
    {
        dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Name = GetPkName(dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Table, dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Columns);
        base.Generate(dropPrimaryKeyOperation);
    }

    // Prefix + TableName + "Col" + ColumnName + And + ColumnName (and only applies with composite PKs)
    string GetPkName(string tableName, IList<string> columns)
    {
        string columnNaming = "";
        if (columns.Count > 1)
        {
            columnNaming = string.Join("And", columns.Select(c => c).ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            columnNaming = columns[0];
        }

        return PREFIX + tableName.Substring(tableName.IndexOf('.') + 1) + "Col" + columnNaming;

    }
}
```

This worked perfectly when adding a new table with a PK or even a composite PK (which will result in pkTableColColumnAndColumn.  The only issue i was having was when I would change a primary key and it would call `protected override void Generate(DropPrimaryKeyOperation dropPrimaryKeyOperation)` Both the other override functions for createTableOperation and addPrimaryKeyOperation have the appropriate Columns objects populated.  However, the dropPrimaryKeyOperation does not have the columns object.

I am a bit new to this API and would appreciate any ideas on how to get the dropPrimaryKey function to give me the current columns that are the PK.

Once I get this all sorted out, I am planning on using a similar process for renaming the FK Constraints.