# Entity Framework 5 code first newsequentialid() as PK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, newsequentialid

How can I use `newsequentialid()` as default value in the PK column?

I have this annotation:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

But this will generate random guid's I would like to have sequential guid's.

I can set by hand the database to `newsequentialid()` as default value, but is there no better option? Or did the EF team forget about this option?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using migrations you should be able to simply modify code based migration to use `newsequentialid()` as `DefaultValueSql`.

```
public override void Up() {
    CreateTable(
        "SomeTable",
         c => new {
            Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "newsequentialid()"),
         })
         .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    );
}
```

If you are not using migrations check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098972/guid-comb-strategy-in-ef4-1-codefirst).

Comment: i had to add Key and DatabaseGenerated comma seperated to make it work, if they are added seperately, then it not works